# Internal error when creating YDN app

Tags: yahoo-api

I'm trying to create a Yahoo Developer Network (YDN) app, but all I get is this: An internal error occurred (eid 5480371).

There's no way to send a support email and it says on Yahoo's site to use this channel.

Comment: I am also having this issue.

Comment: Are you still having this problem? Two days later, and I'm here with the same error.

Comment: Yes it's still showing an error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its working again...